# sqrt(-1) is broken. What happened?

Tags: processing.js

I'm trying to let `i` be the square root of -1 (`sqrt(-1)`). It is a ***defined*** value:

```
i = sqrt(-1)
```

```
var i = sqrt(-1);
fill(0, 0, 0);
text(i, 25, 25);
```

It gives me an error. What happened?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting a NaN error.

Comment: and what is the value you believe it should have? Because in Processing, the result is `NaN`, so it's doing exactly what it should be doing. Also, I archived pjs in December of 2018, so even if this _was_ a bug (which it isn't), it'd never get fixed.

Comment: Unless explicitly asked for, most programming languages do not use complex numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqrt()` is a function that already has a defined behavior. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt):

> The square root of the given number. If the number is negative, `NaN` is returned.

`NaN` is not an error in itself. It's a value that means "not a number" - you can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

You seem to be thinking about functions and values in a different direction than I would. Looking at this line:

```
var i = sqrt(-1);
```

This line isn't saying "define the square root of -1 to be equal to i". It's saying: create a variable named `i`, and set its value equal to whatever is returned by calling `sqrt(-1)`.

So the code calls `sqrt(-1)`, which returns `NaN`, so the value of `i` is `NaN`. Then when you try to use that value, you'll see `NaN`.